# how to check if TextView has image in android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have a layout with multiple [TextView's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView). When the user clicks one I check if the the `TextView` has a background. If it has a background I remove it, else if it doesn't I set it.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So my question is, how do I check if the `TextView` already has a background set?

Update

```
if( textView.getBackground() == null) {
                    Log.i("here", "null");
                    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draw_cross);

                 }

                 if(textView.getBackground() != null) {
                     Log.i("here", "not null");

                     textView.setBackground(null);

                 }
```

Comment: it is not clear how ImageView is used in your question.

Comment: I just said I dont want to use ImageView.I want to if there us a way to check TextView has icon on it or not

Comment: I have edited your question, if I understand what you want help with, accept it and ill give you the answer! Also please update your tag with what language you are using during runtime, Kotlin or Java.

Comment: I approved your edit.Thank you for making question clear.Can you give me answer?Language is java

Comment: Thank you, and no problem. I have submitted an answered to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following code:

Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (hasBackground(v)) {
                    v.setBackground(null);
                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draw_cross);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean hasBackground(View v) {
        return v.getBackground() != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I tried your code now but when textView is null,setBackgroundResource does not set image.I updated my question,could you please look at what is wrong in code?

Comment: That was my mistake.Thank you for your help.I got the solution.

Comment: No worries glad I can help! I updated my answer with a full Activity example just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Background-Drawable by using

```
myTextView.getBackground();
```

If it is null, no Background is set, otherwise it is.
Then you can do something like this:

```
if(myTextView.getBackground() == null)
    myTextView.setBackground(myDrawable)
else
    myTextView.setBackground(null)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , I tried code too, but does not image to TextView

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely fulfil your requirement -

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
int count = 1;

tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(tv.getBackground() == null)
        {
            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draw_cross);
            count = count+2;
        }
        else if(count%2 != 0)
        {
            tv.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    }
});
```